# Property 'spaceBetween' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'

Tags: reactjs

I am encountering an error when attempting to use **Swipper** in a React/Typescript project.

my code is :

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";

function CustomSwipper() {
return (
  <Swiper spaceBetween={50} slidesPerView={3}>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
 );
}

export default CustomSwipper;
```

No additional code has been written.

the complete error:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; spaceBetween: number; slidesPerView: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'.
```

Property 'spaceBetween' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes & SwiperProps'.

I could not find helpful answers to my question on StackOverflow or other websites.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: yes, I'm using typescript in reactjs